# Is it possible to remove hideous outline around a TSpeedButton glyph?

Tags: delphi, glyph

I've run into a bit of a snag, is it just me or can you not assign an image from a resource to TSpeedButton's glyph without a hideous black outline as shown below?

I've assigned it exactly the same way for the TImage component and I'm getting the result needed.

I've been searching for quite a while but no one seems to have this bizarre and annoying problem.

Here's my source code for the form below:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var r : tresourcestream; png : tpngimage;
begin
  r := tresourcestream.CreateFromID(hinstance,34,'cardimage');
  png := tpngimage.Create;  
  png.LoadFromStream(r);  
  png.AssignTo(image1.Picture.bitmap);  
  png.AssignTo(speedbutton1.glyph);  
  png.Free;  
  r.Free;  
end;
```

34 is the image of type 'cardimage' that relates to the image being shown in the picture if you haven't guessed already.

[image]

Comment: The issue is clearly that the alpha channel is ignored in the left picture.

Comment: Generally, you should call `X.Assign(Y)`, not `Y.AssignTo(X)`. If `TX` doesn't know how acquire attributes from a `TY`, it will defer to `TY` by calling `Y.AssignTo(X)` automatically. But if `TY` doesn't know how to assign itself to a `TX`, it won't defer to the target object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue is clearly that the alpha *channel* is ignored in the left picture. Now, the `TSpeedButton.Glyph` property is a `TBitmap`, so it might be problematic to preserve the PNG alpha channel. For example,

```
var
  png: TPNGImage;
begin
  png := TPngImage.Create;
  png.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Pictures\alpha.png');
  SpeedButton1.Glyph.Assign(png); // or png.AssignTo(SpeedButton1.Glyph);
```

produces

[image]

One partial solution is to pre-blend the PNG image:

```
var
  png: TPNGImage;
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  png := TPngImage.Create;
  png.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Pictures\alpha.png');
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  bm.SetSize(png.Width, png.Height);
  bm.Canvas.Brush.Color := Self.Color;
  bm.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height));
  bm.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, png);
  SpeedButton1.Glyph.Assign(bm);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Ken. But there might be a better solution.

Comment: I would +1 if I could lol, but Thanks works a treat! It's only being used for a school project, and was just annoying my eyes lol but thanks yet again! :D

Comment: pre-blending's going to gîte you some grief somewhere down the line.

Comment: Nit-pick :) guess you don't need a second bitmap, can draw directly to the button glyph..

Comment: @Sertac: Oh, yes, quite true.

Comment: FWIW, I am personally going to rewrite TSpeedButton to have proper PNG support. Some day. When I have time.... [grins]

Comment: Very nice, this is something that should be native. Amazing even in XE2 the buttons still dont support PNG by default.