# A button control and underlying replacement for TBitmap that properly handles PNG transparency without writing pre-blend code

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2010, png-transparency

Delphi 2010's TSpeedButtons  did not seem to really support PNG transparency properly, because the Glyph property uses a TBitmap internally, and TBitmap is for bitmaps, and doesn't support PNG transparency properly, and TSpeedButton.Glyph can't support transparency then.. **update: But the actual problem was that I had some external stuff (Developer Express components) that was rendering delphi's PNG support non-functional, TImage on the other hand, while it still TPicture, and can support PNG, was also affected by this Developer express bug.**

A question was already asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305519/is-it-possible-to-remove-hideous-outline-around-a-tspeedbutton-glyph), and the answer shows how to use pre-blending so that transparency won't turn into black pixels.  I want to know if there is another button control that will use alpha-blended PNGs loaded at designtime, and which does not convert the PNG resources into BMP format discarding the alpha channel and, causing the black border shown here.

In short, this control would not use TBitmap, and would not use the color key transparency feature that is all TBitmap has.

To repeat, I am not asking how to solve the black-around-the-outside issue while still using the out-of-date TBitmap/TSpeedButton based VCL functionality, because it lacks modern PNG transparency functionality, I am asking about replacing it with something else that "just works".

As a secondary drawback, converting a small .png file into a .DFM bitmap resource is essentially wasting space and making my form .DFM content too large. Native .png file format storage within the .dfm should make the resulting forms smaller.

[image]

**Update:** PngComponents look like they should work, but I got  an `Invalid Graphic format` error when I try to load a png into the Png speedbutton.  Note that the Png image list component has no such problems.  It seems that cxLibrary (a developer express package) is breaking things. Once I removed all developer express stuff, this problem goes away. So although I have selected Pngcomponents as the answer, if you have devex stuff installed, use their buttons instead, and not pngcomponents.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to put images in the dfm then don't, load them as resources. This is the only sensible approach in my view. If you put your assets in the dfm files then you lose the ability to keep the assets in revision control.

Comment: Why don't you put your PNGs into .ico files and load them into an image list at runtime?

Comment: P.S. Hope the new job is working out for you!

Comment: TToolBar buttons with an image list should work, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may have a look at [PngComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127). It has a TPngSpeedbutton and some other controls working directly with PngImages.

Comment: Thanks. Looks good! I think I had heard of them before but never checked them out.

Comment: I had a problem getting .PNGs to load at designtime with PngComponents, and tracked it to an old RXLIB designtime package, which I removed. Now I get Invalid Graphic format exception: [2108C8A0]{designide150.bpl} PicEdit.TGraphicProperty.Edit (Line 272, "PicEdit.pas" + 10) + $12

Comment: confirmed.  Developer Express cxLibraryD15 breaks PngComponents. Removed devex stuff from my ide (we don't use it anymore) and no problem. but since lots of people do use it, I'm leaving the note above in the question.  It seems that if you use developer express components, the easiest solution is their own cxButton.

Comment: PngComponents registers the old TPngObject class in the initialization section of PngFunctions.pas. This will allow loading older forms made with the old PngImage implementation. Other libraries may be doing something similar, which might be the cause of the crash. As I have no DevExpress components at hand in the moment, I cannot figure that out by myself.

Comment: I haven't had DevExpress and still had this error. I have only CnWizards and GExperts. The only way I managed to get rid of the error was to associate explicitly with 'PNG' extension in PngFunctions.pas like this: "TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('PNG', 'PNG File', TPNGObject);"

Answer (score 2):

You could also look into the TMS Software Component called TAdvGlowButton as this supports PNG images with alpha transparency.

[Link to site...](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advglowbutton.asp)

Comment: I have used this button and it's quite nice!  The TMS stuff is pretty great in general too.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that cxButton that comes in the Developer Express VCL component pack also supports PNG buttons.

Comment: Also it turns out that developer express stuff at PngComponents are mutually exclusive. Pick one.